# Share pass store between two computers

Tags: password

I recently switched to pass as password manager and I am very happy with it, but I would like to share the passwords between two machines (work and home). I duckduckgo-ed how to do it properly, But couldn't find any solutions. Am I particularly dumb, or is there a way to easily do this?

Best,
/E

Comment: LastPass works across devices (including mobiles). How does this relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: @User24601 OP seems to be using [different software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_(software)).

Comment: @Melebius I see that in the question but does pass work across devices or have I misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use LastPass (free version) which I can use on any device and my passwords are automatically synced across them including my mobile phone - handy for logins to online banking apps for example. The master password to access LastPass is extremely strong.

See [this](https://support.logmeininc.com/lastpass/help/lastpass-free-faqs) reference which explains how LastPass works and its benefits in the circumstances you describe.

What's included in LastPass Free?

- Access on all supported devices
- One-to-one password sharing
- An encrypted Vault to store and manage your site passwords, secure notes, and form fill items
- Save and fill site passwords
- Storage with secure notes
- Easy web form filling
- Secure password generator
- Extra security with Multifactor Authentication, including the use of the LastPass Authenticator
- Password auditing using the Security Challenge

If you don't already have a LastPass account, you can get started by signing up for a free trial [here](https://lastpass.com/create-account.php) Once your free trial expires, your account will automatically convert to a LastPass Free account.

Comment: Just tried LastPass and it's exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @E.B. Great stuff - thanks for the feedback. I upvoted your question as it will be useful for others to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want it to be synced right?
you can connect a cloud space(Next-cloud for example) to your file browser and keep your "pass file" in there so you can access it from work and home and it will be synced.

[how to add online accounts](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/accounts.html.en)
[Browse files on a server or network share](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-connect.html.en)

Comment: I guess this might work, but I had issues with my (a bit broken) installation. I tried LastPass as from the other reply and worked fine for me. Still, thanks for the answer, i will keep in mind when I'll upgrade my system.